# Prevent smart Contenteditable paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can prevent smart Content-editable paste with allow smiles like Facebook?

I search on Stack overflow and found many answer but it's too old and not working as i expected.

I want to make it totally like Facebook on Facebook it's allow only the smiles image and prevent any HTML codes.

Comment: And what you did till now?

Comment: @timiTao i am not a professional programmer if i found a old answers i try to make it working if i failed i ask here for help so i try and failed and asked this question. Need to know anything else?

Comment: The content you did till now - what you try, what your read, what did and what code you produced - maybe you was nearby solution, but forcing people to repeat your step wont help you find answers. Help people to help you.

Comment: This is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/tb8ryyp6/3/ i just want this code not remove <br> and accept images that with class emoji.

Comment: If you add any crucial information(like your code) - always add it to question by edit it - not let them in comments - for others to check that easly. You should add your code directly to question too. Then you will have chance that someone will help you - don't count that other will do extra effort, if you didn't want.